Do gods do any tapas on supreme entity?
Does gods like sun and moon did any Tapas on supreme entity? If they did then what was it like to mankind? and what did they ask for?
If a sun or moon closed their eyes and do Tapas, then who will run their duties? Who will give light and energy to earth?
I know gods like Lord Brahma, Ganesha, Parvathi, Shiva, Vishnu did tapas, but my question is about Lord Sun, Lord moon, Lord Indra, Lord Yama, Lord Agni etc. What is the differences between these 2 kinds of gods?
